# React + Typescript: How can I type a button that sometimes uses "as={Link}"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button component that I sometimes want to transform to a `Link` for UX purposes using `to={Link}`. Other times I want it to stay a button.

However, Typescript is treating my button as always a link element, and links don't have a `disabled` property.

```
const Container = styled.button``;


export interface ButtonProps {
  to?: string;
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const Button = ({
  to,
  disabled = false,
  onClick,
}: ButtonProps) => (
  <Container
    as={to && Link}
    onClick={to ? undefined : onClick}
    disabled={disabled}
  >
    click me
  </Container>
);

export default Button
```

Typescript returns this error

[image]

Is it force typescript to view the component as a button or link, depending on whether `to` exists?

Comment: Does it happen if you set conditions before `Container`? I mean like 
`if(to) return <Container as={Link}/> else return <Container />`.

Comment: I am nou sure, but does `button` has `as` attribute?

Answer (score -1):

Try annotating the Button functional component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ to, disabled = true, onClick }) => {
   ...
}
```

That is the functional version of `class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps>` and is TypeScript's way of defining what props the component should expect.

The `: ButtonProps` prop annotation won't be necessary anymore when you use the interface on the function as shown above.